# Proving $\Delta^nx^n=n!h^n$.

Tags: numerical-methods

How can I prove $\Delta^nx^n=n!h^n$.  Here $\Delta$ is forward difference and h is the step size.
I used induction .
When $n=k$ assume the result is true.

$$\begin{align}\Delta^{k+1}x^{k+1} &= \Delta^k(\Delta x^{k+1}) \\
&= \Delta^k[(x+h)^{k+1}-x^{k+1}] \\
&=\Delta^k[x^{k+1}-k(x+h)x^k+k(k-1)x^{k-1}(x+h)^2+....-(x+h)^{k+1}] \\
&= \Delta^k(x)^{k+1}-k\Delta^k(x^k+1)+hk\Delta^kx^k-k(k-1)[\Delta ^k (x^{k+1}+2h\Delta^k x^k)]+ ....-\Delta^k(x+h)^{k+1}\end{align}$$

I don't understand how to prove the inductive step.Is my approach correct?can some one please show me how to prove this?

Comment: A simple way is given by showing that, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$, then $\Delta p (x)$ is a polynomial with degree $n-1$, and the leading coefficient of $\Delta p(x)$ is just $hn$ times the leading coefficient of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach can be made to work. First, you need to know that $\Delta$ is a linear operator, so that

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta^{k+1}(x^{k+1})&=\Delta^k\big(\Delta(x^{k+1})\big)\\\\
&=\Delta^k\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}\ell x^\ell h^{k+1-\ell}-x^{k+1}\right)\\\\
&=\Delta^k\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k+1}\ell x^\ell h^{k+1-\ell}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k+1}\ell h^{k+1-\ell}\Delta^k(x^\ell)\;,\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

where of course the first second step is just the binomial theorem, and the last step is linearity of $\Delta^k$. Then you have to show that if $k>\ell$, then $\Delta^k(x^\ell)=0$. I suggest taking as your induction hypothesis not just that $\Delta^k(x^k)=k!h^k$, but also that $\Delta^k(x^\ell)=0$ if $\ell<k$. With that extra hypothesis you can simplify $(1)$ very easily to get what you want. You will, of course, have to complete the induction step by showing that $\Delta^{k+1}(x^\ell)=0$ if $\ell\le k$, but this is very easy given your induction hypothesis.

Comment: @clarkson: You're welcome.